# Pocket door latch side is higher than the other

Tags: pocket-door

My pocket door has become uneven.  The latch side is higher than the other side and the roller cannot be seen. What is the easiest way for me to readjust the door?  It rolls a little hard, but does close, just lopsided.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky, you can just lift the door and hook it back on to the track.

But that probably won't work. Usually, you have to remove the trim at the top of the doorway to get access to the tracks and rollers.

Comment: Yup, the roller assemblies will have a height adjustment screw, I can just get to mine with a long skinny screwdriver without removing the trim molding. I cut a small notch in the top of the door at both roller locations to make access easier.